# Placed stronghold in INVALID biome

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft SMP 1.0

```
Placed stronghold in INVALID biome at (4, -70)
Placed stronghold in INVALID biome at (46, 30)
```

I get this message when server starts. What does it mean? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a stronghold being generated in an invalid location, such as under sand. From what I can gather, clearing your player data and running [Chunkster](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admin-chunkster.8186/) (backup first) on your world should fix the problem.

Comment: I did run it, nothing has changed: in those locations there still is no stronghold; does this mean they have been created elsewhere, or that they have not been created at all?

Comment: I'm not sure. This is a very old question on the Minecraft timescale, the biome generation and stronghold placement code has been updated multiple times since this question was asked.

Comment: Can you think about a method to discover if there are valid strongholds somewhere? Should I follow this question http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30340/how-can-i-find-my-worlds-strongholds or is there a cheaper method to just check if they exist?

Comment: Get yourself an eye of ender and see if you can find one!

Comment: I thought about that, but what if there is _just one_ instead of all three?