# How to locate fortresses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find my World's Strongholds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30340/how-can-i-find-my-worlds-strongholds)

Is there any reliable tool for determining the locations of Fortresses and Nether fortresses in Minecraft?
We migrated our server to the latest version of Bukkit. Since we have quite a bit of the map already revealed, I'm not sure whether we still have a chance of finding a fortress in the overworld.
So instead of running around the map, I'd like to use a tool to find their locations and then check whether those chunks were already generated.

Similarly, is there such a tool for Nether fortresses? (Even this isn't such a pressing issue, since there are supposed to be many of them.)

Comment: It isn't clear from your question - do you know that eye of ender has ability to locate an ender portal?

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo Umm... no? Is that somehow related? :3 (TBH, I like surprises, so I haven't studied the updated content _at all_. The question, however, is something the players on my server will want to know.)

Comment: The Eye of Ender, when thrown like a snowball, will fly towards the closest stronghold. You can read more about how to get and use it [on the Minecraft wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Eye_of_Ender). Tell, if this answers your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall help a lot https://yogscast.com/showthread.php?29349-Minecraft-Stronghold-Finder!!-1.8.1

You need your seed, then get a program that is a fortress locator, it will tell you the coordinates of all 3 fortresses.

This is for strongholds, not Nether Fortresses.