# How do I find a stronghold?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Apparently you're supposed to throw an Eye of Ender, but that doesn't work. How else can I find one?

Answer (score 0):

## *With* Eyes of Ender

Yes, you throw an Eye of Ender to find the stronghold. This can be easily found with a quick [Google search](http://bfy.tw/2nGS).

And [an answer on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30340/how-can-i-find-my-worlds-strongholds).

> As of 1.9-pre4, you can use Eyes of Ender to locate the direction of a stronghold by throwing them up in the air. Once thrown, they'll change direction to point to the stronghold.

The above is still how it's done, despite the fact that it was done for **1.9-pre4**.

It is better to have more than one Eye of Ender, as they are easily lost wasting your time, but it will come to a point where the Eyes keep going to a single point on the ground. This point is where the stronghold lies. Dig down and you shall find.

## *Without* Eyes of Ender

Not to offend, but choosing to do such a thing, is highly unlikely to fetch results, and is even more likely to take a lifetime, but there are multiple ways to achieve this.

**Exploration Method**

The "Exploration Method" solemly relies on your abilities to scan  your world from top to bottom, by searching for an entrance. The thing is however, Strongholds don't have an entrance, so the "Exploration Method" only really works for underground caves and systems which may lead into the Stronghold itself.

**Map Method**

Another alternative to this, is to use a map viewer, and look around for anything "Stronghold" suspicious. Here is another extract from the [brilliant answer on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30340/how-can-i-find-my-worlds-strongholds).

> There is no in-game way to find a stronghold, but you can use a cartography program like MCMap Live (Mac) or Cartograph G (Windows) (see also this question for other alternatives) to look for tell-tale signs of a stronghold: iron bars and bookshelves.

Here is an image from the answer showing an example of what to look for **(Enhanced)**:

[image: Enhanced image of a stronghold on a Map Viewer.]

Good luck!

Comment: I'm slightly concerned that you've answered what is essentially "*how can I find a Stronghold without using Eyes of Ender?*" with "*use an Eye of Ender*"

Comment: @JonK I'm sorry? I dont understand?

Comment: The question asks for alternative methods for finding Strongholds instead of using Eyes of Ender. Your answer basically says to use Eyes of Ender - in that sense you've not answered the question

Comment: @JonK Ah, makes sense now; thanks. The question in general, hints that the OP is not using their Eyes of Ender correctly, so I have shown them the correct way to. However, I will also add to it, with what you've just said. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I certainly agree with you in that regard - I share that suspicion, and it's why I haven't downvoted

Comment: @JonK Addition added. ;)

Answer (score 0):

To clarify. When it is said to throw.. they don't mean pressing q. (Or circle or b on consols) but to activate using right click (or left trigger on consol)

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get achievements make a copy of your world and activate cheats in the copy. From there use the /locate command an example is (/locate endcity ) <--  so then remember or copy the coordinates and just go to them in the original world and this works with anything. This is a easy way to find any location in Minecraft!